# How to update total score by programme

Tags: android

I would like to update score in Activity without refresh the activity.

I have the code bellow with 1 TextView and 3 Buttons.

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/score"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/q1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/q2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/q3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Upadte Score Activity:

```
final TextView TxtScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);  

final int UpdateScore = i.getExtras().getInt("UpdateScore");

final Button q1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.q1);
final Button q2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.q2);
final Button q3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.q3);

q1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){

        if(answer.equals("correct")
        {

           TxtScore.setText(Integer.toString(UpdateScore + 1));
        }   
        else
        {

           TxtScore.setText(Integer.toString(UpdateScore - 1));
        }
     }
});

q2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){

        if(answer.equals("correct")
        {

           TxtScore.setText(Integer.toString(UpdateScore + 1));
        }   
        else
        {

           TxtScore.setText(Integer.toString(UpdateScore - 1));
        }
     }
});

q3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){

        if(answer.equals("correct")
        {

           TxtScore.setText(Integer.toString(score + 1));
        }   
        else
        {

           TxtScore.setText(Integer.toString(UpdateScore - 1));
        }
     }
});
```

The code above is not working as what I need, it working individual update to the TextView when onClick.. but I want to automatic update the score, example bellow

Example the carry score from previous is: int score = 10;

- when q1 is press "Correct". The score will update to 11;
- when q2 is press "Incorrect". The score will update to 10
- When q3 is press to "Incorrect". The Score will update to 9

something like this.

But I really stuck on the giving score automatically update.

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: the code you post does not compile. Post the original code. The crashlog as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only god knows what that code is suppose to do, the errors are enormous.

In any case do this:

change `final int score = 0;` to `int score = 0;`

change every `int x = score + 1;` to `score = score + 1;`

change every `int x = score - 1;` to `score = score - 1;`

change every `UpdateScore.setText(Integer.toString(x));` to `UpdateScore.setText(score  +"");`

...

Wait wait, do you have all of that inside the `onCreate()` method? If so, move all the variable declarations outside it, make them class/activity level.

EDIT====

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView TxtScore = null;
private Button q1 = null;
private Button q2 = null;
private Button q3 = null;

private int score = 10; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...

    TxtScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    q1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.q1);
    q2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.q2);
    q3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.q3);

    /* And your onCLickListeners right here with the changes I pointed out. */

    q1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){

            if(answer.equals("correct") {
                TxtScore.setText(++score +"");
            } else {
                TxtScore.setText(--score +"");
            }
        }
    });

    ....

}
```

Comment: Yes.. I have all of these in onCreate(). I follow you instruction but just start the Activity is crash. Anyway thanks you so much.

Comment: No dude, seriously, I didn't mean to be an ass, check my answer, I changed it, included almost full code. Let me know.

Comment: Oh..I got what you mean. let me try again sir.

Comment: Hi LuckyMe, Thank you so much it's working well for me. Again thanks you so much.

Comment: Hi LuckyMe, I would like to ask you again, if the value of score I want get from score = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("score"); ..I mean score value is getting other activity. what I should do?

Comment: From the activity coming to this, add this to the intent: `intent.putExtra("score", score);`, and in this use what you got: `getIntent().getIntExtra("score", 0);`.

Comment: you i put private int score = getIntent().getIntExtra("score", 0); in class level.. if this one, I already test but it crash.

Comment: You need to learn programming in general before you are able to make applications, what I just said is very basic programming concepts, you can go into making an app by doing it like this. Once you learn how to program, then go through this training to learn how to program in Android: http://developer.android.com/training/index.html Sorry aside from that I can't keep doing this.